# laravel FormBuilder getMethod issue

Tags: php, laravel, formbuilder, getmethod

The getMethod function implementation does not accept all HTTP verbs except `POST`, `GET`?
My use case is this

- Form open to an update resource, so method should be `PUT`.
- I built one access control library to check if the user has access to the { resource, 
  method }
- I am using `getMethod()` to get method name, but it always returns `POST` even if the parameter sent is `PUT`.
- As this is returning `POST` always, `ACL` always returns `NO_ACCESS`

Any reason why `getMethod()` is written this way?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would check to make sure your web server allows PUT requests.  I had an issue with the web server only allowing GET and POST by default.

I'm assuming you're doing something like `if( Request::getMethod() == 'POST' )`?

Since laravel's Request class extends Symfony's you can try using `Request::isMethod('post')`.  This is my preference and it reads better IMO.